# Mongoid: how to set embedded object (embeds_one relation) without persisting

Tags: ruby, mongoid

Say I have the two models:

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_one :address
end

class Address
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :person
end
```

I am trying to set the address of a created `person`, without the `address` being persisted to the database.

```
person.address = Address.new # Automatically persists address to the database.
```

My question is basically the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521691/mongoid-embeds-many-push-document-without-save-in-order-to-preserve-dirty-state), except this is an `embeds_one` relationship, so the `build` method is not available. I have seen the dynamically created `build_<embedded_object>` method, but it does not seem to accept the same options as `build`, namely the specific class with which to build the embedded object (it's a subclass of the associated class):

```
person.posts.build({
  name: "Another post"
}, SpecialPost)
# Works

person.build_address({
  name: "An address"
}, SpecialAddress)
# Does not work
```

Comment: This `person.address = Address.new` does not save the address to db until you call `save`. right?

Comment: If `person` is already persisted, yes, it does.

Comment: So, it means, if you assign the `address` using `person.address = Address.new` and then do `person.reload`, you can access `person.address`?

Comment: That's right, and I can see the mongodb update in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

The address embeded in person will not be persist by default, when you run

`Person.new(...)`

It will be persist only if you add autobuild to be true

`embeds_one :address, autobuild: true`

and also set

`validates_presence_of :address`

The latter will make sure it will be persist in database.

Or you could assign address to person object without saving it.